# Adjusting axis’ ticks in plotting with SymPy

Tags: plot, sympy, implicit, xticks, yticks

Here is the problem:
I have two implicit functions **F and G**. I am trying to find a way to plot them using SymPy.

My question is, how to adjust ticks on x- and y-axis, so I can see a crossing point of my functions? How to add visual quality to my plot?

[image]

[image]

I’ve tried to add “points” to increase the quality, but it didn’t work well. I have no idea how to deal with ticks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With quality, I assume you would like to improve the smoothness of the lines. Sadly, the way `sympy.plotting.MatplotlibBackend` is coded makes it impossible to improve it.

To achieve a better result you should use [SymPy Plotting Backend](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/graphics/functions_2d.html#spb.graphics.functions_2d.implicit_2d), which solves a tons of problems affecting `sympy.plotting`:

```py
from sympy import *
from spb import *
var("x, y")

e1 = (x**2 + y**2) * (x + y) - 15 * x * y
e2 = (x**4 + y**4) * (x**2 + y**2) - 85 * x**2 * y**2
ranges = (x, -10, 10), (y, -10, 10)
graphics(
    implicit_2d(e1, *ranges, color="purple", label="e1"),
    implicit_2d(e2, *ranges, color="pink", n=301, label="e2"),
    grid=False
)
```

[image]

Note that I used `n=301` when plotting the second expression (odd number of discretization points). Given your current ranges, it will place a discretization point on `x=0` and `y=0`, making the visualization more accurate.

SymPy Plotting Backend by default uses standard Matplotlib layout, which places the ticks on the bottom and on the left of the figure. This make your intersection point visible.

Final note: next time copy your code as text, not as an image.

**EDIT** to satisfy user request:

In this code block I'm going to plot all solutions where the two curves intersect each other. Note that:

- I create real symbols by providing `real=True`. This will compute real solutions.
- I used `list_2d` to plot list of points.
- `rendering_kw` is a dictionary of keyword arguments that will be provided to matplotlib to customize the appearance. In this case, it will be passed to Matplotlib's `plot` function.
- Instead of modifying the axis ticks, I decided to show both major and minor grids. In my opinion, it makes the plot more readable.

```py
from sympy import *
from spb import *
import numpy as np
var("x, y", real=True)

e1 = (x**2 + y**2) * (x + y) - 15 * x * y
e2 = (x**4 + y**4) * (x**2 + y**2) - 85 * x**2 * y**2
sols = solve([e1, e2], [x, y])
print("solutions:", sols)
# solutions: [(0, 0), (2, 4), (4, 2)]
xx = [s[0] for s in sols]
yy = [s[1] for s in sols]
ranges = (x, -10, 10), (y, -10, 10)
graphics(
    implicit_2d(e1, *ranges, color="purple", label="e1"),
    implicit_2d(e2, *ranges, color="pink", n=301, label="e2"),
    list_2d(xx, yy, scatter=True, label="all solutions"),
    list_2d([0], [0], scatter=True, label="my marker", rendering_kw={"marker": "x", "markersize": 10}),
    grid=True, show_minor_grid=True
)
```

[image]

Instead, in this code block I'll modify the axis ticks. Note that:

- I created a hidden plot.
- Then, I extracted Matplotlib's axes in order to further customize the output.
- I created the `ticks` and `ticks_labels`. You can be creative with `ticks_labels`, as long as it has the same number of elements of `ticks`.
- Finally, I used Matplotlib's `plt.show()` to visualize the plot.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p = graphics(
    implicit_2d(e1, *ranges, color="purple", label="e1"),
    implicit_2d(e2, *ranges, color="pink", n=301, label="e2"),
    list_2d(xx, yy, scatter=True, label="all solutions"),
    list_2d([0], [0], scatter=True, label="my marker", rendering_kw={"marker": "x", "markersize": 10}),
    grid=False, show=False
)
# extract Matplotlib's axes from the plot object, p
ax = p.ax

# create ticks
ticks = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.5)
ticks_labels = [str(t) for t in ticks]
ax.set_xticks(ticks, ticks_labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, adding ticks with a step of 0.5 is going to make the ticks very difficult to read. You will have to play with the step.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will note for myself to copy the code as a text next time. But what to do with adjustment of x-axis? I need it to be with a step of 0.5 but  not 2.5? How I can put a marker at the point of the solution F = G?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show you how to achieve your goal.

Comment: That is working! I can’t thank you enough 

Comment: Is there any option to scale the x axis so the labels don't overlap? So if the user wants tics at 0.5 then the axis is drawn wide enough so that the labels don't overlap (i.e. don't have text collisions)?

Comment: @smichr Users of SPB can set the size of the plot with `size=(width, height)` keyword argument. Increasing the width will avoid the tick labels to overlap. Another option would be using the axes object (as in the answer) to rotate the tick labels.